# get ID of record from datagridview in c# and show the data to another form

Tags: c#

i am building a very basic / entry level application for learning the c#, i want to pass the id of record to another form and there i can fetch the record by writing query.
i was following this youtube tutorial

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-4t2CFAOwo

But it dint helped me out. The code i have tried is

```
 private void load_data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        container_departure_details cdd = new container_departure_details();
        cdd.Show();
    }
```

it shows the next form but i am unable to pass and get the id value in second form called

> container_departure_details

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can use the CellClick event of the datagrid to get the value of cell with the ID.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // get the row index of the cell clicked
        var rowIndex = e.RowIndex;

        //specify 0, if the Id is in the first Column else in place of 0 e.ColumnIndex
        var id = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;

        var newForm = new Form();
        newForm.Show();

    }
```

Comment: ok by trying your code, it passes the values to newFrom? and how can i get that value in newForm? Thanks once again ..

Comment: i found modified your solution lit bit by taking help from this article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/834980/how-to-pass-data-from-one-form-to-other-form-in-windows-form/ and its working fine now, will share final code in my comments

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Mr. Donnie** his answer really helped allot, after some minor modifications to his answer I successfully get the value to other form. Final code is

```
public static string SetValueForText1 = "";
        private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // get the row index of the cell clicked
            var rowIndex = e.RowIndex;

            //specify 0, if the Id is in the first Column else in place of 0 e.ColumnIndex
            var id = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            SetValueForText1 = id;
            var newForm = new container_departure_details();

            newForm.Show();
        }
```

and on form2 in my case it is **container_departure_details** get the value by following line

```
record_id.Text = inspection_report.SetValueForText1;
```

inspection_report is the name of form

for more details visit this link 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/834980/how-to-pass-data-from-one-form-to-other-form-in-windows-form/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the SelectionChanged in DataGridView.
for example:

```
private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.SelectedRows) 
    {
        string value1 = row.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString();
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: ok javad, but i have a question, if i am not wrong, on SelectionChanged it get the value of id and on every SelectionChanged it popups the form2, on which i want to get the value to id?

Comment: yes, by this way on every SelectionChanged you can get Id of Current Row and popup the Form2. I think you need get Id for each RowChanged.